# How do I return the the historical data for the past X years until current day for a stock using yahoo finance data?

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve the historical data for the stock AAPL, but the below code has me specify between certain dates. How can I make it so that it automatically pulls the data for the past 5 years until current date instead?

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd

ticker = 'AAPL'
period1 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 23, 59).timetuple()))
period2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 28, 23, 59).timetuple()))
interval = '1d' # 1wk, 1m

query_string = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'

df = pd.read_csv(query_string)
print(df)
df.to_csv('AAPL.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yfinance` to retrieve the data,
install using pip:

```
pip install yfinance
```

Use this code to retrieve the past 5 years of historical data of 'AAPL',

```
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download('AAPL', period='5y')
```

You can also use `yf.Ticker` to do it:

```
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
df = ticker.history(period="5y")
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it is working. Do you know if this is live ticker data? I can't really test since the market is closed right now. Also, do you know how to output this data into my local sql server SSMS?

Comment: @Empyz
I'm not sure if it's real-time.
I don't work with sql so I can't help with that, if you face any problem with "how to output this data into local sql server SSMS", then post this on SO, I'm sure someone will be able to help.